# Calculate maximum number of thread that can be used for better performance in a Threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I face a interview where interviewer asked me about what will be maximum thread you can assign to thread pool. I answered him it will be depend upon hardware combination. 
Also I can manually test execution by increasing threads in thread-pool.

He seem to be not happy with that.

can anyone tell how can we decide what will be the maximum threads we should use for better performance. any guide link will be appreciated(In core java application)

Comment: "***can anyone tell how can we decide what will be the maximum threads we should use for better performance***" This is a different question and much more difficult to answer. Do you want an answer to this sentence or an answer to your title (and previous paragraphs)?

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s internal state limits the thread count to 2^29-1. The OS and memory likely become the limiting factors well before that. Also, the constructor accepts only an `int` which sets the limit lower.

Comment: There are 2 different questions here. If you are asking what the max thread pool can be, then then answer is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If  you are asking what it should be - the answer to that is based on a number of factors depending on the requirements, etc.

Comment: yes @Donal sorry if I written it wrongly. My question was that only how to determine maximumthreadpool , which factors involves

Comment: @coreJavare The answer is not straightforward. See here: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-Thread-Pool-Performance-Tuning

Comment: If he wasn't happy with that you should have asked him what kind of an answer he was looking for. Not much point in asking us. Many interview questions of this sort are really the interviewer showing off his probaby inaccurate knowledge, or madcap theories, rather than a genuine investigation into your knowledge. In this case I would have given a rather deep answer from statistical queueing theory, and possibly he wouldn't have been satisfied with that either. If he was really asking for answers based on `Integer.MAX_VALUE` etc., he was just wasting everybody's time.

Comment: Or, to give the interviewer the benefit of the doubt, he wanted to hear you reason about how to decide what the optimum number of threads would be, and you didn't. For example, he may have wanted you talk about the difference between I/O bound threads and CPU bound threads.

Comment: The first thing you really should have asked back is “which thread pool”? In Java you can have more than one thread pool and there are more than one thread pool implementation. So before we can answer any question about “thread pool” we have to know what “thread pool” the interviewer is asking about. Regarding the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` that has been written several times, there is no reason to name that number. Either we are talking about a particular implementation available today, then the number is smaller, or we are talking about a theoretical limit, which is much higher (think 64 Bit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Can anyone tell how can we decide what will be the maximum threads we should use for better performance** - it's definitely not maximum amount of threads.

For the best performance, amount of threads should be equal to **number of processor cores** (don't forget to use **-XmsYYYYM** and **-XmxYYYYM**, without them you can face situation when your processor not assigning threads to the cores).

About maximum threads your answer was correct, it depends on hardware and OS.
On linux it can be checked:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

**edited.**

You can create thread pool with **Integer.MAX_VALUE**

But **you limited** with amount of maximum thread usage.
On my laptop. Command "cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max" shows me **126987**.

Code that I ran :

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestMaxAmountOfThreads {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService serivce = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
      serivce.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          }
        }
      });
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> 31850
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to
>   create new native thread  at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:949)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1360)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
>     at
>   com.stackoverflow.test.TestMaxAmountOfThreads.main(TestMaxAmountOfThreads.java:10)

So I can use only **31850** threads, without jvm tuning.

Comment: @Donal Hard to see what difference that makes, or indeed what the question is really about at all.

Comment: So it’s time to learn about `-Xss` to control the stack size. Smaller stack size means more threads…

Comment: Holger, yeah , there are a lot of VM args that we can play around, but this value will be not more than 126987, for the current laptop with the same OS.

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` class constructor definition like below-:

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,**int maximumPoolSize**,long keepAliveTime,TimeUnit unit,BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,ThreadFactory threadFactory,RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

You can assign the maximum value of integer(`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) to maximumPoolSize. Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance problems. If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task switching overhead becomes a significant factor.

Answer (score 0):

> Calculate maximum number of thread that can be used for better performance in a Threadpool

The answer to this question depends entirely on the kind of task each thread will perform.

On one side, if your program is [**CPU bound**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound), then the number of running threads should not be higher than the number of CPU cores. Some Intel processors have an "Hyper Threading" feature which [is known to affect **CPU bound** tasks](https://bitsum.com/pl_when_hyperthreading_hurts.php), so you should consider disabling Hyper Threading at all.

On the other side, if your program is not CPU bound but [IO bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) entirely, then the number of threads should not be higher than 2 or 3 times the number of cores available. If you have 8 cores, you should not go higher than 24 threads for a IO bound program.

In the middle, if your thread pool needs to perform mixed CPU bound and IO bound operations, you should test and measure the performance with different output, and decide for your specific case a reasonable number. There is no theoretical way to find a concrete number, you should run some concrete benchmarks on your specific application.

This of course depends entirely on your program, and if you have a program which is entirely IO bound, then I'd say that you stick with just one thread and take advantage of non blocking asyncronous IO API available in major platforms. In Java we have [Non-blocking IO (NIO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29).

Comment: good ++1 - how did you arrive at this number `On the other side, if your program is not CPU bound but IO bound entirely, then the number of threads should not be higher than 2 or 3 times the number of cores available. If you have 8 cores, you should not go higher than 24 threads for a IO bound program.`